# Mesh formation in the wells of SDS PAGE. How to solve it?

Tags: molecular-biology, sds-page

I casted 10% resolving gel and 4% stacking gel and every time a mesh like structure ( polymerisation) in the wells are formed.How to avoid this from happening and how do i get clear wells? If someone has any idea about it, it will be a great help. Thank you

Comment: Have you tried rinsing the wells with buffer? Do you have an image of this problem? How old are the chemicals you use - especially TEMED and APS?

Comment: Is the comb the right thickness for the spacer you’re using?

Answer (score 1):

This issue is driving me crazy too. Although I haven't identified the exact cause, here are the steps I've taken to minimize mesh formation:

(1) Prepare your gel on the same day you plan to perform SDS-PAGE. Do not store your gel in the fridge overnight.

(2) Allow the stacking gel to harden for a longer period (>40min). I suspect that the mesh forms when the stacking gel hasn't hardened sufficiently.

(3) Switch out the comb. It's possible that mesh formation is associated with a specific comb. Mark the comb number and monitor any mesh formation.

(4) Prepare more gel than you actually need. In my experience, some gels with mesh formation occurred while others did not. By making a few extra gels than needed, I was able to select the gels without mesh formation for my experiments.

All these steps are based on speculation; nothing has been proven yet. Good luck and please share your experiences if you get any improvements!